# Where to load secrets/.env in intern

Tags: intern, 12factor

I'm setting up our e2e testing service with intern and want to keep my secrets (sauce labs key etc) in a .env file using the npm dotenv library. in order to do that i need to `require` it somewhere. Where would be the earliest place I can do that? My intern configs all inherit from a base configuration, so i plan to use that for now- but is there somewhere earlier?

for the record, this is a self-contained testing service, not part of another framework and i'm using this library: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

In case there is no better point of entry, I'm updating with my own solution which injects the environmental variables prior to loading the intern.js config module:

```
define( ['intern/dojo/node!dotenv'], function (dotenv) {
    dotenv.config();

    return { intern config object };
});
```